# Is there a way to control pageWidth property of xPage Bootstrap app. layout?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, xpages, lotus-notes

Here are two examples with app. layout and with just navbar that have pageWidth="fixed"

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xe:applicationLayout id="applicationLayout1">text
    <xe:this.configuration>
        <xe:bootstrapResponsiveConfiguration pageWidth="fixed"></xe:bootstrapResponsiveConfiguration>
    </xe:this.configuration>
</xe:applicationLayout></xp:view>


<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xe:navbar id="navbar1" pageWidth="fixed"></xe:navbar>
    <xp:br></xp:br>text
</xp:view>
```

How do I get and change pageWidth size/margins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not using the app layout, rather have built my own nav bar, however if I understand correctly, I achieve what you want by putting the nav bar within the container div, and have custom CSS which sets the container width. Anything within that div only stretch's as far as that width. The end result for me, is I have 2 area's of white space, one to the left and one to the right, and a content area in the middle (inc navbar), which I can make smaller or larger by simply editing the container width in CSS???